# Imgur issues in questions and rejecting upload

Tags: discussion, bug, imgur

I've noticed a few questions today with images across multiple site (auto mechanics and GD.SE) haven't been loading in the questions and per discussion with a few other members they've experienced the same issue in chat.

All image issues seem to be loaded to imgur: `https://i.stack.imgur.com/whatever`

At this time, I'm told when I try to upload an image of what I'm seeing I get:

> Failed to upload image; imgur is rejecting the request